# Override a css bootstrap property I can't access

Tags: css

I'm trying to find a css trick to make a vertical align middle on the content of td cells.

So the html structure is

```
<tr class="myLine">
    <td class="notMyCell"> content cell </td>
</tr>
```

By default bootstrap setup `vertical-align:top` on td.

Problem is, the whole content of td isn't handled by my part of the application. That means, I can't set `vertical-align:middle` on the `.notMycell` class. I can't even put inline css on this td. I have none control on the whole line. I can't just create my own css for the `notMyCell` class because some day this classname could change.

I'm trying to setup a property into `myLine` class that would let me ovveride the one from the td.

I'm not even sure this is possible.

Thanks for your assistance any ideas would be good to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said the `class` could change.
So you could use the `data` property to find the element.

```
<tr class="myLine" data-id="customrow">
    <td class="notMyCell"> content cell </td>
</tr>
```

and then in your `css`

```
[data-id="customrow"] > td {
    vertical-align: ... !important;
}
```

Use `!important` to overwrite the `css`.

Comment: Damn actually I just see the css used is a core one, so I can't add the property like that. I will probably find a work around and eventually use your solution, but while this is pending is there a way to write the same thing with an inline `style = ...` on the tr ? I don't know if childs selector are existing in pure html.

Comment: Inline style applies only for the element that has the inline style

Comment: Tell us more about your situation, why are you not able to add or change anything?

Comment: It's all fine I've been able to link a new css file by adding a dynamic import...but nevermind, this works fine thanks^^

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, we just need to write the code like this -:

- If you are using CSS

  ```
  .myLine > td {
      // your custom css
  }
  ```
- If you are using SCSS/LESS

  ```
  .myLine {
       td{
           // your custom css
       } 
   }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors are all about specificity.  The more specific a selector, the higher it's precedence when deciding what styles to use.

Why this is important is because `.myLine > td` is *less specific* than `.notMyCell`, and therefore any styles you set on the first selector will be lower in precedence then those on the second.

However, you could try to be even more specific:

```
tr.myLine > td.notMyCell {
    vertical-align: ...
}
```

Which will be more specific than `.notMyCell`.

Of course, you could always use `!important` to override it (although it's not a great work-around imo):

```
.myLine > td {
    vertical-align: ... !important;
}
```